# Job status is marked as Running when the pod is still pending for being scheduled

Tags: kubernetes

I noticed my job status is marked as Running when its pod is still pending for being scheduled. Is there a way to get the actual status from the job resource itself without looking at the pod resource?

Job:

```
$ kubectl describe jobs sample-job
Name:           sample-job
...
Start Time:     Sat, 28 Sep 2019 13:19:43 -0700
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age    From            Message
  ----    ------            ----   ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  2m16s  job-controller  Created pod: sample-job-ppcpl
```

Pod:

```
$ kubectl describe pods sample-job-ppcpl
Name:           sample-job-ppcpl
Status:         Pending
Controlled By:  Job/sample-job
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
...
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                  From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  29s (x7 over 6m25s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) didn't match node selector.
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Job system understands "done and succeeded", "done and failed", and "still going" as statuses. Running means that it has requested that the job run, not that it's literally executing.